# How many ways can you distribute 3 types of candies to 8 children?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a big bag of candy. Peppermints, Chocolates, and Caramels. There are eight sweet children who deserve candy. One each, they are not that sweet. So I give each child a candy. How many ways are there for the candies to be distributed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there will be a standard answer to this question somewhere and wouldn't be surprised if this is a duplicate.

However, assuming you've got enough of each sort of candy (which 'big bag of' suggests), each child can have either of the three types of sweets. So, child one has 3 possible candies, child two has 3 possible candies and so on. For the first two children there are $3^2=9$ options this way (here you can still write down the options, if you like) and each successive child adds a factor $3$. Can you see why?

The result then would be $3^8$ ways to distribute candies (which equals $6561$, if I am to believe google). The questoin would be a lot harder if the amount of candies of each type would be restricted.